# Prove or disprove that the product of $ 2^{0.5} $and $ 7^{0.5} $ is irrational

Tags: calculus

How do you prove that is true for this 2 numbers? 
I tried already by the same proof of $ 2^{0.5} $ but not sure it is true to do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The number $2^{0.5}\cdot 7^{0.5}=\sqrt{14}$ is rational iff $\sqrt{14}=p/q$ for some positive integer $p,q$. Hence
$$p^2=14 q^2.$$
Are you able to get a contradiction from that?

Hint. Count the factors $2$ (or $7$) on both sides of the equation and use the [unique factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

P.S. Note that the same strategy works if you replace $14$ with any integer number which is not a perfect square.

Comment: Is it works the same as the proof of  2^0.5?

Comment: @Adi Yes, it is quite the same.

Comment: But 14 is not a primary number.. so it is not the same

Comment: @Adi. It is not necessary to have a prime number. What you need is a number which has in the factorization a prime raised to an odd exponent. So prime numbers are only a particular case.

Comment: @Adi Any further doubt?

Comment: I think it is ok. Thanks a lot